# Python-MySQL-Google Developer Console

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-sql, mysql-connector-python

I am rather new to programming.

I have accidentally created connections to Google Cloudsql instance by Python without realising.

Trouble is, I did not include close connection in the script and now I am with 7 active connections unclosed.

I have tried using  "mydb.close()" and leaving it overnight but none works it only closes the new scripts.
So please could anyone give me a hand on how to close these active connections ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: mydb.close() will only close the current session not previous ones. In the docs they have this short paragraph describing how you can close the connections: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#how_usage_calculated . The quick and dirty fix is explained at the end. "You can also you restart the instance to kill all the connections.2

Comment: If you're not using the Cloud SQL instance, your could deleted to be sure is not waken up.